# How to get my popup images to keep showing up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I am developing a webpage with thumbnails that are served up from a local geoserver. The desired effect is to have the thumbnail expand into a dialog window that can be moved around. I am able to create the dialog box and expand the thumbnail, but when I close the dialog box it removes it until the page is reloaded. This is the xslt where the source of the images is and how the html is created:

```
<xsl:for-each select="cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:resourceMetadata/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:fileInformation/gmd:MD_FileInformation/gmd:rasterTypes">
                                                                            
                                                                    <!-- shift the context to the lookup elements -->
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="raster_label">
                                                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$metacard_label-top">
                                                                            <xsl:with-param name="curr-label" select="@codeList"/>
                                                                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                                                                    </xsl:variable>                     
                                                                            
                                                                    <xsl:choose>
                                                                        <xsl:when test=". != ''">   <!-- If the element value is not null, display it. Else display attribute value. -->
                                                                            <xsl:value-of select="." /> - <xsl:value-of select="$raster_label" /><br />
                                                                        </xsl:when>
                                                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                            <xsl:value-of select="@codeListValue" /> - <xsl:value-of select="$raster_label" /><br />
                                                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                    </xsl:choose>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="rasterType" select="cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:resourceMetadata/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:fileInformation/gmd:MD_FileInformation/gmd:rasterTypes"></xsl:variable>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="identifier" select="/tdf:TrustedDataObject/tdf:HandlingAssertion/tdf:HandlingStatement/edh:ExternalEdh/edh:Identifier"></xsl:variable>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="codeLVal" select="@codeListValue"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_min_long" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:westBoundLongitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_min_lat" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:southBoundLatitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_max_long" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:eastBoundLongitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_max_lat" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:northBoundLatitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <img class='AOIMapFir' src='/api/thumbnails/npsi?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300&amp;layer={$identifier}_{$codeLVal}' onerror="this.setAttribute('src','/api/thumbnails/edcss?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300');" height= '85' width = '100'></img><!-- this works -->
                                                                    <div id="dialog" class="hide-dialog" style="display: none"><img class='aoi' src='/api/thumbnails/npsi?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300&amp;layer={$identifier}_{$codeLVal}' onerror="this.setAttribute('src','/api/thumbnails/edcss?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300');"></img></div>
                                                                </xsl:for-each>
```

This is the javascript that currently controls the click function. I found that the click event has to be in the render function of the javascript.

```
   $('.AOIMapFir').on('click',function(evt){
    
    
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: ".widget",
        title: "Area of Interest",
        resizable: false,
        close: function(event,ui){
            var holder = "<div id='dialog' class='hide-dialog' style='display: none'><img class='aoi' src='$(this).attr('src')' ></img></div>"
            $('#dialog').dialog("destroy").remove();
            $(this).append(holder);
        },
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: ".container"
                   },
        width: "auto",
        overflow:"auto",
        height: "auto",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        show: { effect: "blind", duration: 200 }
    });
    // $('.aoi').attr('src', $('.AOIMapFir').attr('src'));
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    
    // $("#dialog").dialog("close", function(evt){
    //  $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");
    // });
    $(".ui-widget").css({
        "font-size": +10+"px",
        "background-color": "none"
    });
});
```

This is a screenshot before the thumbnail is clicked:

[image]

This is a screenshot after the thumbnail has been clicked:

[image]

So again, my problem is that after I close the window I am not able to open it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your close function:

```
close: function(event,ui){
            var holder = "<div id='dialog' class='hide-dialog' style='display: none'><img class='aoi' src='$(this).attr('src')' ></img></div>"
            $('#dialog').dialog("destroy").remove();
            $(this).append(holder);
        }
```

You're destroying and removing the #dialog div, then trying to append to it -- the `holder` is never appended, since there is nothing to append to.  (You should able to confirm this by running some console logging -- note that if you `console.log($(this))` you'll get a non-empty result, because `this` is not a reference to a lookup but a javascript DOM element object created at the beginning of the function by the `#dialog` selector; try `console.log($('#dialog'))` to  confirm that it's no longer there.)

An easy way around this is to allow the dialog to simply close, rather than destroying and removing it.  You can do this by removing the `close` key in your initialization entirely:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: ".widget",
    title: "Area of Interest",
    resizable: false,
    position: {
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: ".container"
               },
    width: "auto",
    overflow:"auto",
    height: "auto",
    closeOnEscape: true,
    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 200 }
});
```

Or, if you need to do something in your close function, by directly calling [`$('#dialog').dialog(close)`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close):

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    ...
    close: function(event, ui) { 
      ... // do whatever you need to do here
      $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I had to use the .remove() function because when I tried to open a new dialog by clicking another thumbnail, the only expanded thumbnail it would show is the expanded version of the first thumbnail on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I completely fixed my problem by having to append an element that uses the source of the thumbnail clicked to get the expanded thumbnail. I removed the one from the xslt. Here is the xslt:

```
<xsl:for-each select="cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:resourceMetadata/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:fileInformation/gmd:MD_FileInformation/gmd:rasterTypes">

                                                                    <!-- shift the context to the lookup elements -->
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="raster_label">
                                                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$metacard_label-top">
                                                                            <xsl:with-param name="curr-label" select="@codeList"/>
                                                                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                                                                    </xsl:variable>                     

                                                                    <xsl:choose>
                                                                        <xsl:when test=". != ''">   <!-- If the element value is not null, display it. Else display attribute value. -->
                                                                            <xsl:value-of select="." /> - <xsl:value-of select="$raster_label" /><br />
                                                                        </xsl:when>
                                                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                            <xsl:value-of select="@codeListValue" /> - <xsl:value-of select="$raster_label" /><br />
                                                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                                                    </xsl:choose>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="rasterType" select="cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:resourceMetadata/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:fileInformation/gmd:MD_FileInformation/gmd:rasterTypes"></xsl:variable>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="identifier" select="/tdf:TrustedDataObject/tdf:HandlingAssertion/tdf:HandlingStatement/edh:ExternalEdh/edh:Identifier"></xsl:variable>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="codeLVal" select="@codeListValue"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_min_long" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:westBoundLongitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_min_lat" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:southBoundLatitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_max_long" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:eastBoundLongitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <xsl:variable name="aoi_max_lat" select="$current/cdpeenv:CE_Metadata/cdpeenv:subjectMetadata/cdpeenv:CE_Subject_Metadata/cdpeenv:CE_Coverage_Metadata/cdpeenv:extent/gmd:EX_Extent/gmd:geographicElement/gmd:EX_GeographicBoundingBox/gmd:northBoundLatitude/gco:Decimal"/>
                                                                    <img class='AOIMapFir' src='/api/thumbnails/npsi?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300&amp;layer={$identifier}_{$codeLVal}' onerror="this.setAttribute('src','/api/thumbnails/edcss?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300');" height= '85' width = '100'></img><!-- this works -->
                                                                    <!-- <div id="dialog" class="hide-dialog" style="display: none"><img class='aoi' src='/api/thumbnails/npsi?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300&amp;layer={$identifier}_{$codeLVal}' onerror="this.setAttribute('src','/api/thumbnails/edcss?bbox={$aoi_min_long},{$aoi_min_lat},{$aoi_max_long},{$aoi_max_lat}&amp;width=400&amp;height=300');"></img></div> -->
                                                                </xsl:for-each>
```

Javascript:

```
render: function( model ) {
  var that = this;
  this.$( '.mc\\.display' ).remove();
  this.$( '.ph' ).remove();
  this.$( '.content' ).append( this.addRowShading( model.get('html') ) );
  this.$( '.mc\\.display' ).metacardView();
  this.$( '.mc' ).css('height', $(window).height()-220+'px'  ).mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"cdpe-preview",
    advanced:{
      updateOnContentResize: true
    }
  });
  this.createExpandingAttrs();

  //this.$( '.mc\\.display' ).metacardView('setTabContent', { name:'oob', title: 'Order of Battle Hierarchy' , content: '<div id="oob_hierarchy"></div>'});
  this.$("#oob_hierarchy").jstree({
    "json_data" : {"data": model.get('oob-tree-json') },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ],
    "themes": { "theme": "classic", "dots": false, "icons": true }
  })
  .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
      if(data.rslt.obj.data("unit-info")) {

        that.toggleUnitInfo(data.rslt.obj);
      }
  });
  //this.$( '.mc\\.display' ).metacardView('setActiveTab', { tabName: 'oob' } ); 

  this.delegateEvents();
  $('.AOIMapFir').on('click',function(evt){
    var that = this;
    var source = this.src;
    // Alertify.dialog.alert(this.src);
    var holder = '<div id="dialog" class="hide-dialog" style="display: none"><img class="aoi" src="' + source + '" ></img></div>'
    $(that).append(holder);
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: ".widget",
        title: "Area of Interest",
        resizable: false,
        close: function(event,ui){
            $("#dialog").dialog("destroy").remove();
        },
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: ".container"
                   },
        width: "auto",
        overflow:"auto",
        height: "auto",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        show: { effect: "blind", duration: 200 }
    });
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    $(".ui-widget").css({
        "font-size": +10+"px",
        "background-color": "none"
    });
});
},
```